# how to implement the custom grid using jquery

Tags: jquery, gridview, jqgrid

I am using asp.net mvc3 razor application, before i start with mvc3 i want to create mockup screen using simple html page. So i want to create grid using jquery, one of the column details in grid loaded from Database table. The edit and save button need to design in top of the grid.So once i press the edit the whole grid field need to be editable, no need to show the popup like that.

One think is the grid input fields are need to validate before save in database..how can achieve this using `Jquery`.? Please suggesting the best approach..

If you need more details about my case, please let me know..

Comment: have you looked at jqGrid ?

Comment: hi ryadavilli..thanks for your response..i will look at it..is it possible for cell formatting in jqGrid?

Comment: Please check http://jqgrid.com/. They claim to support CSS customization, so I believe you will be able to use CSS and/or jQuery for formatting.

Comment: I want to set the edit mode for the entire gridview rows on a button click and then update all the rows with another button. How can i implement like this using jqGrid?